# Sounds lost after interruption

Tags: iphone, audio, openal

I'm using the SoundEngine provided with Apple's crash landing example.

After an interruption such as an incoming phone call or an alarm I call to applicationWillResignActive: inside my delegate, in order to pause the game and save the state of it. After the interruption ends I return to my game but the sound is gone. Even if i reinitialize it with SoundEngine_Initialize() the game still wont reproduce any of the sounds, unless i restart my app.

How can I restore my game sounds after the interruption ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at the sound manager class used by 71squared ?  You can likely just use their sound manager as is...  but if you wanted to role your own, you can look at thier code as I know they have solved this in their code.

http://www.71squared.com/2010/01/latest-sound-manager-class/